# Do we have a password reset adaptive card in MS Teams?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, change-password

I am creating a password reset flow and wondering if we an adaptive card which includes 'new password' and 'confirm password' n a single card. Something like below

[image: Password reset card]

I know I could use 2 adaptive card with Input.text and style = password to achieve this. Wondering if we have anythign else.

Comment: What do you mean by "do we have"? Are you asking if such a card already exists as an official Adaptive Cards sample, or are you asking if there's a way to make such a card? Why not just put two text inputs in the same card?

Comment: Hey @KyleDelaney, yeah I was checking if we have an official Adaptive Card. Can I use two text inputs in the same card? I did not know about this. I will give it a try. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple input test box in a single adaptive card. to add New password and conform password you can use two input boxes in the single adaptive card.

Example:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Please enter your new password below:",
            "wrap": true,
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "New Password*",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "***************"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Repeat New Password*",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "***************"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I just want to note that it's probably a security breach to have users send passwords to bots